# A description for a changing-wording-of-a-website framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a Ruby gem, which allows programmer (or whoever) to change wording on their Rails website.

When the edit mode is activated, every text on the website will have an edit icon. User can click on that edit icon and change the corresponding text immediately.

It works with text, attributes of any element, select element, and string in Javascript.

Now I don't know how to describe it succinctly.

Right now the description is "[WhowishWord](http://github.com/tanin47/whowish_word) facilitates the process of changing wording of a website".

I think the description is bad and vague. Maybe there is a regular keyword for this kind of task (changing wording) that I do not know.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: What's wrong with edit mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current wording "Have you ever been bored when a project manager (or marketing department) keeps changing wording on a website? WhowishWord facilitates the process of changing wording on a website." requires changing a bit.

I would suggest that you divide your description into several logically ordered paragraphs. Also mention the cost and where from could people get it.

0 - Contains a short description as you did but without the word "bord" and without specifying actors who ask for the change since every case is usually different.

1 - List who would be interested in this tool: Web site designers, admins, etc.

2 - List the technology that your tool demands and the technology you used to build it (if important)

3 - List the features your product has.

4 - Ask for feedback (give the address)

5 - Possibly attach a video showing how it works

Comment: I have vaguely follow your instruction and, eventually, I come up with a good description.

I describe WhowishWord as "A wording framework for Rails"

Comment: I have checked it out and I'd say that it is very good :)